# How to search for specific thing in model file using CoreML

Tags: ios, swift, object-recognition, coreml

I'm trying to create object recognition app where it can find specific thing on the video frame.

As a newbie I knows how to let the CoreML to tell what it is on the video using iPhone's rear camera. but how to reverse doing it by let user type specific string e.g.. people, dog, tree etc. and create a bounding box around each one of them?

Thank you in advance for any suggestion

Comment: What model are you using?

Comment: "create a bounding box around" - The task you want to solve is called object detection, and the object recognition you've mentioned is a different task. 
Check this for Core ML implementation of YOLO object detection algorithm: http://machinethink.net/blog/yolo-coreml-versus-mps-graph/

Comment: @Pochi I'm using inceptionV3

Comment: @AlexanderSosnovshchenko thank, for informative ex.